# @UniqueConstraints failing on update

Tags: ejb-3.0, unique-constraint

I have an Entity class in which I put uniqueconstraint annotation

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"staffRecord_id", "defaultLabel_id","company_id","keyCode"})})
public class AllowanceDeduction implements Serializable{
---
```

What I have noticed that is when I try to save on the table
using

```
 if (allowanceDeduction.getId() == null) {
            this.entityManager.persist(allowanceDeduction);
        } else {

            this.entityManager.merge(allowanceDeduction);
        }


when the save or update fails due to a unique constraint. Isn't it only supposed to fail when trying to save a new record that is identical to a record that already exist.
```

Why would it fail when trying to merge or update?
Please help needed

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure but it looks like you're trying to persist a null id

```
if (allowanceDeduction.getId() == null) {
        this.entityManager.persist(allowanceDeduction);
        /* don't you need the id set to a non-null value in order to persist it? */
    } else {
```